# javers complains when a field is declared as Collection but initialized as concrete type

Tags: javers

Using javers 1.4.1.

I have a field in a POJO declared like this:

```
private Collection<String> names;
```

and then initialized with an instance of a concrete `Collection` class like this:

```
names = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I run tests against this class, javers complains with the following error:

`JaversException: MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR given javaClass 'class java.util.ArrayList is mapped to java.util.ArrayList, expected ManagedType`

The same error if I initialize it inline, like:

```
private Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

On the other hand, if I declare the field as a `List` then javers is happy:

```
private List<String> names;
```

---

I'm a total newb to javers, it was introduced to the project by someone else. But all I did was add this new field to an existing POJO. What do I need to look at and/or tweak to make javers happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, JaVers has to know (statically) if it is a List or Set. Without that information, JaVers doesn't know how to compare two collections. So you have to change your POJO's.

This error message is a bit misleading, there is an issue for that here https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/353

I would expect something like `High-level Collection interface is not supported, try at least Set or List`

Comment: That's a bummer; I prefer to declare fields as the most abstract type that makes sense, in this case that would be `Collection`. Any chance this limitation of JaVers could be corrected?

Comment: Nope, it's not an error, that's the way JaVers works. JaVers uses different algorithms for comparing Sets ans Lists. How you gonna tell JaVers which one to choose?

Comment: At runtime couldn't it use reflection to determine the actual type?

Comment: and what if you will have Set at the left side and List at the right side?

Comment: btw, just to determine an object type `instanceof` is enough

Comment: I think I'd expect that scenario to result in the two fields being deemed not the same, period (no further information). Like if I declared a field as `Object` and the left side was a `String` and the right side was a `Boolean`.

Comment: By the way, if we want to further explore this idea, should probably create an enhancement request at GitHub to continue the discussion.